# Redirect to subdirectory only if not only in that subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am facing a (probably) quite simple problem with my plain old php application. I have a website with a simple directory structure:

```
www.domain.com
  /blog
  /some_subdirectory
  /some_other_subdirectory
```

I would like to redirect the user to the /blog directory everytime he visits any folder/any file in my application except except if he is already in that /blog directory.

I have come up with the following snippet inside my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 302 / http://www.domain.com/blog
```

but of course this will also redirect if inside the /blog directory, causing an infinite loop of redirects to deeper /blog directories that don't exist.

How can I exclude the /blog directory from that redirect statement?

Comment: @faa You had an awesome answer down there - why did you remove it? :)

Comment: Because Jon's is almost identical and was posted 5 seconds before.

Comment: True, sorry - removing the `,R` does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite instead because you can create a negative condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,R]
```

This, of course, changes what's in your browser's URL address bar. If you don't want the bar to change, then simply remove the `,R` flag from the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude a folder, you should use mod_rewrite. You may try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/blog     [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*) /blog/$  [L,NC]
```